# Microsoft Graph - how to get metadata (columns) of a Sharepoint Library

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am able to update the metadata (displayed as columns) of an existing file, but that requires which metadata I will manage. But how could I get the columns which have been defined on the library?

To update known metadata, I do the following:

```
graph = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives/{drive_id}/items/{item_id}/listItem/fields"
                new_values = {
                "Client": "NOUVEAU_CLIENT",
                "Date_x0020_de_x0020_facturation": "2023-08-30T00:00:00Z",
                "Pointage": False
                }
                response = requests.patch(graph, headers={'Authorization': access_token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, json=new_values)
```

I've tried various get requests, but no way to get the so_called fields at the library level.

When I do :

```
graph = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives/{drive_id}"
response = requests.get(graph, headers={'Authorization': access_token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

I get a response with no informations about columns, fields, just id, description, name, drivetype,... createdBy, lastModfiedBy, owner and quota

Any help is welcome,

Richard